# MVVM Light - Relay Command Parameter value coming intermittently

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm-light

I am using a silverlight application. Trying to bind a button's click command to a relay command in ViewModel and passing some parameters to it. Code for my View is :

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="173,0,152,0">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=button, Mode=TwoWay}" Command="{Binding CRelayDecimal, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

A button is passing it's ActualWidth as parameter for command's parameter. My ViewModel  code is:

```
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CRelayDecimal = new RelayCommand<Object>(this.GetDecimal);
}

public RelayCommand<Object> CRelayDecimal { get; private set; }

private void GetDecimal(Object Obj)
{
    var value = (double)Obj;
}
```

Now, the problem I see here is that most of the time passed parameter value I receive is  0.0. Intermittently, I've seen value to be precise value (like.. 75.0) that it should be.

Is there any other way of doing it ?

Thanks you all for your help in advance.

Thanks and Regards

Nishant Rana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay Got the answer why this was not working.. because it's a known issue in silverlight.

Read [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522231/silverlight-grid-stackpanel-canvas-actualheight-and-acutalwidth-is-0) link for details from MSFT.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's pulling the binding value of "ActualWidth" from the DataContext, which is likely the ViewModel (where ActualWidth doesn't exist as a property).

This might work.  You could try setting "this.button.DataContext=this;" in the Loaded event handler of your view code. So the view becomes the first-choice datacontext of the button.  Unresolved binding properties such as CRelayDecimal should still fallback to the ViewModel.

Or perhaps the easiest thing to do is to just hook up an ordinary click handler on the button for the view code to handle. The view code would compute the ActualWidth off the event sender and send the RelayCommand for the model as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is at least one another to do this. From your example, it does not make sense to use `Command` because you just want to send a value from View to ViewModel.

I suggest you use Messenger to send value between View and ViewModel. What you have to do are:

1) Register to a message in your ViewModel. I prefer to do this in its constructor. You also have to add a method to handler the callback from the messenger. Please note that `"tokenId"` use to make sure that you send the message to intend subscribers.

```
Messenger.Default.Register<double>(this, YourMethodHere, "tokenId");

private void YourMethodHere(double value)
{
    // do your work here
}
```

2) Inside the View, you have to add an event to the button and just send the message through the messenger.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Messenger.Default.Send<double>(this.ActualWidth, "tokenId");
}
```

3) You can `Unregister` the subscribtion on the ViewModel in its destructor to prevent mutiple message sending.

Comment: using an button's default 'Click' event, wouldn't be a expensive call compare to command? However, in my believe commands parameters can serve this purpose more elegantly for current situation, isn't it?

Plz, correct me if my understanding is wrong ?

Regards
Nishant

Comment: I have never test the performance of click event compare with command binding. I expect they have a very slightly difference, maybe 1 or 2 seconds if you load test them for a million times. In my opinion, it does not make sense to test or to worry about that.

Comment: Yeah, true there is not a huge difference in performance but still advisable to use command instead because they don't even have memory leak hazard like event can cause if we do not handle them properly.. I thought of sharing it as knowledge sharing :-) However, your suggested solution is also an elegant way which can be useful for more complex situations.. and once again thanks for your feedback and help !!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for your feedbacks!

I investigated it further and found that problem is due to with property I bound to it i.e "ActualWidth". If I try to bind it to property "Width" then it works fine.

Therefore, I believe it's taking only the initialization value for "ActualWidth" property.

Let me do some more test and then i'll get back to you with more results.

Thanks and Regards

Nishant Rana